# Apex Charts - Unable to hide data labels and set colours values

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I've created a pie chart following the base documentation for Apex Charts, and I seem to be unable to hide the data labels on my pie chart (and set the colors as well).

**Code sandbox** - https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-pie-simple-forked-qlgxz

**Colors documentation** - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/

**Data Labels documentation** - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it appears that the issue I had was due to responsive breakpoints within the chart, which I had to set these colours at each break point respectively. I haven't yet found an improved solution.

```
      responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      options: {
        chart: {
          height: 130,
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        legend: {
          position: "left",
          labels: {
            colors: "#FFFFFF",
            useSeriesColors: false,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 5000,
      options: {
        colors: ["Red, Green", "Blue"],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        legend: {
          labels: {
            colors: "#FFFFFF",
            useSeriesColors: false,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```